# Pandas - why would not my conditional statement does not prevent Negative numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, redis

I am writing python code which stores table at Redis.

after running the code at AWS server, I've noticed unexpected negative data is in my table.
negative number causes trouble for our next process.

so I wrote this code.

```
        # filter more to not leave negative value
        negative_feature = updated_feature[
            (updated_feature[updated_feature.columns] < 0).any(axis=1)
        ]
        
        refined_feature = updated_feature[
            (updated_feature[updated_feature.columns] >= 0).all(axis=1)
        ]
```

and I have saved this 'refined_feature' at Redis using hset with mapping option(sorry I can't open all my code..due to regulations)

after including this to my code and run.. I still see negative data saved at Redis DB.
and I'm so curious why this conditioner statement doesn't prevent negative data.

Thank you for reading. and if you have any idea or opinion for this, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve here? And, what does your data look like?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I think your error is occurring somewhere else. As a side note, it is not necessary to do `df[df.columns]`, you can just use `df` directly (no functional difference, just cleaner code).

Comment: @AkshaySehgal 

what I'm trying to achieve is to prevent 'refined_feature' having any negative value. 

every data type in all columns are float type. and index is string. column numbers and row numbers are frequently changed.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Thank you for side note.
I've also asked chatgpt about this.

it says conditions I've used are only checking values along each columns seperately, rather than checking for negative values in the entire row. which meaning if any column in a row has negative value, but other columns have positive values, this row would be included in 'refined_feature'. and it recommends this code instead.

refined_feature = updated_feature[
            ~(updated_feature < 0).any(axis=1)
        ]

but I'm bit doubtfult about it.

than why would all option exist at pandas?

Comment: the cause of negative numbers are turned out to be UTC datetime used in AWS server. while coding environment wasn't UTC. however, it is not clear this negative proof code does not do it's expected action.